# TaskCompletionSource intermittently does not complete with NServiceBus and WCF

Tags: multithreading, wcf, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, nservicebus

I have an unusual issue with TaskCompletionSource that has me baffled. I have a TaskCompletionSource waiting for the task to complete once i call the TrySetResult. I call this in three places in the code: from a WCF thread immediately to return a value to an APM WCF BeginXXX EndXXX; from another WCF thread to return immediately to the APM; lastly from an NServiceBus handler thread.

I started with the ubiquitous ToAPM provided by MS-PL. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/06/27/using-tasks-to-implement-the-apm-pattern.aspx

I noticed that the two WCF based threads worked 100% of the time. in 100 hours of hard testing, additionally extensive unit tests, I have never experienced a single failure to return a completed task to the AsyncCallback.

From the MS provided ToAPM code, the code uses a ContinueWith on the completed task to call the AsyncCallback in a schedule enabled task.

The problem I have not solved is the NServiceBus threads calling the TrySetResult on the TaskCompletionSource object. I find times of outages, where for undefined periods of time, the call simply fails. I set break points in the code for both the call and inside the ContinueWith code. I get the break point on the TrySetResult always, but only sometimes on the code inside the ContinueWith code.

The following information hopefully will shed some light on the matter.

I use a CancellationTokenSource with a timeout and setting a result to call the TrySetResult on TaskCompletionSource obj. When the above call does not work to move the task to completed, the timeout code fires. This timeout code has never not worked. it succeeds 100% of the time.

What is interesting is this, in the same code that calls the TrySetResult from the NServiceBus thread, when it works, it works as easily calling the cancellation object's Cancel as it does the TrySetResult on the TaskCompletionSource obj.

When one fails they both fail.

Then after an indiscriminate period of time it works again.

This is a WCF server in a production and QA environment and each displays identical results.

What is most weird is the following, for one WCF connection, the NServiceBus thread succeeds and another fails at the same time. Then at times both work, and then both fail. Again, all at the same time.

I have tried a number of things to work around the issue to no avail:

- I wrapped the call to TrySetResult in a TaskCompletionSource + ContinueWith -- fail
- I wrapped the call in a Task.Factory.StartNew -- fail
- I call it directly -- fail

I really do not know what else to try.

I put in checks to ensure that the TaskCompletionSource obj is not completed, and during the outage it is not. 
I put in checks to ensure the CancellationTokenSource object is not cancelled or has a cancellation pending during the outage, it does not.

I examined the objects in the debugger and they seem good.

They just do not work *sometimes*.

Could there be an inconsistency in the NserviceBus threads that *sometimes* prevent the calls from working? 
Is there some thread marshaling I can try?

I searched everywhere and I have not see one mention of this problem. Is it unique?

I am totally baffled and need some ideas.

Comment: You need to post all relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the call from the NServiceBus thread execution. Isolate the call to TrySetResult using a thread such as QueueUserWorkItem or spinning your own thread. Since, the executing resumes using the thread, you may need some additional threads to handle the throughput. Ether spin multiple dedicated threads or use the thread pool. I tested calling TrySetResult in a dedicate threads and they work.

Here is code to demonstrate a single dedicated thread:

```
    public static void Spin()
    {
        ClientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!HasSomething.WaitOne(1000, false))
                        continue;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        WaitingAsyncData entry = null;
                        lock (qlocker)
                        {
                            if (!Trigger.Any())
                                break;

                            entry = Trigger.Dequeue();
                        }

                        if (entry == null)
                            break;

                        entry.TrySetResult("string");
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }));
        ClientThread.IsBackground = true;
        ClientThread.Start();
    }
```

Here is the ThreadPool example code:

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
    {
        entry.TrySetResult("string");
    });
```

Using the ThreadPool rather than static thread provides greater flexibility and scaleability.